# Linux elf binary recuperate file that binary read/writes

Tags: linux, executable, elf

I need to get files that a binary uses.

I can view all dependency of an ELF binary in the `.interp` section, but can I get conf files of my binary?
For example if a binary reads `/etc/host`, I want to see `/etc/host` in a section of my ELF file.

I do not see that in the documentation:
https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_1.1.0/gLSB/specialsections.html

Comment: You should explain **why do you need** to get the list of files written by *which* program. Looks like some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). So please **edit your question** to improve and motivate it.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to get files that some binary executable uses.

**You can't** get (all of) them. A file path used by some executable could be *computed* at runtime (and that is very often the case, just think of the [cat(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cat.1.html) program). Solving that problem (of reliably computing all the files used by a program) in general could be proved equivalent to the [Halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

However, in practice, the [strings(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strings.1.html) utility might help you guess *some* of the files (statically) referred by an executable.

You could also use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strings.1.html) to understand (dynamically) what files are [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html)-ed during some particular execution.

Read also carefully the documentation of your executable. If it is a [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), study also its [source code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code).